# Overriding user edit page with Panels loses the user edit form

Tags: panels

I am using panels to override the user edit page (/user/*/edit) to add a block with a form in it. However I wanted to maintain the existing user edit form, including the password, username, etc. When I overrode the page, I was able to add my block, but lost the original user edit form. I've tried adding the various widgets from the 'User' category (user profile, Profile:Main Profile, etc) on the 'Content' section of the new variant, but they just seem to contain various bits of user information, and none of them add the user form.

How can I add back the user edit form to an panels-overridden user edit page?

Comment: The edit form is available as a pane under one of the categories. I don't have a screenshot available at the moment, but it should definitely be available. :) Content is probably the wrong category though, I would guess the category is named User.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to be misleading, I was editing the content area of the pane, and selecting widgets from the 'user' category (and every other category listed). I haven't run into the user edit widget yet.

Comment: Beware! If you override the user edit page to add an additional form, like I did, you might run into the form in form problem: https://drupal.org/node/1158850 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's fair to say the pane could have had a better name, but here it is.

[image: User edit form location]